# How to implement QuickFix with my c++ project

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, quickfix, fix-protocol

I'm new to the Fix protocol and I've been trying to find a way to implement it into c++ files starting from a XML description file. So by searching on the net they recommended me with Quickfix, what I really want to know is what do we should call QuickFix? A library or a standard or what exactly?

But my main problem is that lately I downloaded the Quickfix package then I couldn't integrate it into my c++ project even with the QuickFix documentation ( which was vague by the way !) so can someone  please describe to me exactly step by step how to configure QuickFix with My Visual c++ project and how can I eventually write this code to parse my XML file:

```
#include "Application.h"
#include "quickfix/Session.h"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickfix doesn't understand XML or parses XML, except for the message bank config file which is in XML. It only deals in FIX formatted strings. You have to use a XML parser i.e. [xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/), [libxml++](http://libxmlplusplus.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/html/) to extract your data in the XML file and then construct a FIX message using the Quickfix library and send wherever you want to.

[Fiximate](http://fixprotocol.org/FIXimate3.0/) is a more user friendly place to check your FIX messages for correctness. There are examples in the Quickfix library to test an application, and you would need a config file to run it, examples are provided on the Quickfix website.

Answer (score 1):

FIX is a standard: [fixprotocol.org/specifications](http://www.fixprotocol.org/specifications/)

QuickFIX is a FIX engine (c.f. Library) implementing the standard.

In the source files that you downloaded there is a set of examples which you can use to understand the operation of the engine. You should use these along side the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

QuickFix is a library. There are other FIX engines also available. 
It simplifies the implementation by taking care of many low-level things. All a developer has to do is enhance the APIs for messages.
There are good examples for a quick start and good documentation for a beginner.
To get into more details of QuickFix, code itself is well organized.